# Insertar datos de c# a MYSQL

Tags: mysql, c#

El siguiente código me da error a la hora que quiero insertar y no se porque me da error.

```
 conectar.Open();
 MySqlCommand add= new MySqlCommand("insert into vuelos1 values('" + FechaLlegada.Text + "," + FechaSalida.Text + ",'" + Destino1.Text + "'," + comboBox1.Text + ",'" + comboBox2.Text + "', " + textBox1.Text);

 add.ExecuteNonQuery();
 conectar.Close();
 MessageBox.Show("Registro Creado");
```

Tengo un campo de `ID` que es `nulo`, `auto_increment` y no se como ponerlo tampoco, aquí les dejo los campos que tiene mi tabla en MYSQL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a tu string, le falta un cierre de comillas simples y cerrar los parentesis. Siempre fijate cual es el string resultante cuando sumas varios, a ver que sale..

Comment: Por favor, siempre recuerda agregar tu error... si te tira un error, pone el mensaje de error en la pregunta

Comment: @gbianchi ahí puse el error que me sale

Comment: Todavía me sigue dando error el código

Comment: En el código publicado no se ve que le asignas la conexión al  `MySqlCommand` y a juzgar por el mensaje de error ese el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las inserciones de texto o de fechas siempre deben ir rodeadas de comillas simples

```
insert into vuelos1 values('" + FechaLlegada.Text + "," + FechaSalida.Text + ",'" +
 Destino1.Text + "'," + comboBox1.Text + ",'" + comboBox2.Text + "', " + textBox1.Text
```

Cuando debería ser

```
insert into vuelos1 values('" + FechaLlegada.Text + "','" + FechaSalida.Text + "','" +
 Destino1.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "', " + textBox1.Text + "'"
```

En tu código

```
MySqlCommand add= new MySqlCommand("insert into vuelos1 values('" + FechaLlegada.Text + "','" + FechaSalida.Text + "','" +
     Destino1.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "', " + textBox1.Text + "'");
```

Estoy asumiendo que los datos que insertas se corresponden con las columnas de las tablas. Sería conveniente (siempre lo es) especificarlas:

```
MySqlCommand add= new MySqlCommand("insert into vuelos1 (campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, ...) values('" + FechaLlegada.Text + "','" + FechaSalida.Text + "','" +
     Destino1.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "', " + textBox1.Text + "'");
```

Comment: No tengo idea de C#, pero: no se puede evitar usar concatenación? Huele a SQL injection :)

Comment: Exactamente. Lo correcto sería utilizar `Parameters.AddWithValue` del `MySqlCommand` para definir los [parámetros de entrada](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) a la consulta.