# Insertar datos de MySQL C#

Tags: mysql, c#

Tengo el siguiente código que me está dando error:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conectar.Open();

        MySqlCommand add = new MySqlCommand("insert into vuelos1 (Fecha_Ida,Fecha_Vuelta,Destino,Gate,Clase_vuelo,Cantidad_vuelos) values('" + FechaLlegada.Text + "','" + FechaSalida.Text + "','" + Destino1.Text + "','" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "','" + ClaseCB.SelectedItem + "', " + CantidadPTxt.Text + "'");

        add.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conectar.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Registro Creado");
        llenar();

       
    }
```

y estos registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me salta este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así es que tengo los **TextBox** en el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si es porque estoy introduciendo mal los valores en los **TextBox**. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: el error es clarísimo, la conexión debe ser válida y estar abierta. revisa que tu cadena de conexión esté correcta

Comment: y otra cosa, entre menos imágenes puedas poner, en pro de poner más código/texto en general, mucho mejor :)

Comment: Saludos, tengo la conexión hecha, porque tengo otro botón con un select hecho y si me funciona, por qué este no?

Comment: Tienes el mismo error de tu compañero. Revisa su pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422122/insertar-datos-de-c-a-mysql

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Insertar datos de c# a MYSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422122/insertar-datos-de-c-a-mysql)

Comment: No, lo he hecho igual y todavía tengo el error

Comment: Tienes `" + CantidadPTxt.Text + "'"` y ahí te falta la comilla simple de apertura. Es un error tipográfico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has omitido pasar la conexión a MySqlCommand. Debería ser:

```
 MySqlCommand add = new MySqlCommand("insert into vuelos1 (Fecha_Ida,Fecha_Vuelta,Destino,Gate,Clase_vuelo,Cantidad_vuelos) values('" + FechaLlegada.Text + "','" + FechaSalida.Text + "','" + Destino1.Text + "','" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "','" + ClaseCB.SelectedItem + "', " + CantidadPTxt.Text + "'",conectar);
```

o en  todo caso:

```
add.Connection = conectar;
```